# Android: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe

Tags: android, react-native, networking, mobile

Recently, my emulators on Android stopped to run projects properly. What follows is: the project is built, the app installs and runs, but never leaves the initial blank/splash screen (also doesn't perform any network calls). This issue is only happening on my Emulators, I can run on physical devices and it works like a charm.

Analyzing the LogCat on AndroidStudio, I have found the following errors:

```
E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
```

Looking for `qemud:network` I found some possible solutions such as adding

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >
```

to AndroidManifest.xml. After changing it, the `'pipe:qemud:network'` seemed to disappear but the `'pipe:qemud:wififorward'` still remains and I can't find any fixes for that. This is blocking me in so many ways right now.

Any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

This may sound really silly, but in my case when I had the problem I was puzzled by a blank screen, and I just had the emulator phone switched off. I hit the ON button and everything worked.